# Is response header "X-XSS-Protection" supported in jsp 1.2?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, xss

I am trying to add the header "X-XSS-Protection" to the response object in a jsp.

my code in jsp...

```
<%
response.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block"); 
System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!Testing X-XSS "+response.containsHeader("X-XSS-Protection"));
%>
```

on the console I get the below result.

!!!!!!!!!Testing X-XSS false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that part of the response has already been written, so it's too late to add headers.

Comment: Does it means we can not add headers inside a jsp..? or Is there any other work around..?

Comment: You can, but it can tricky because you can no longer do this as soon any page content is generated. It's more usual to do this kind of thing in a servlet filter.